# Using ST_Touches in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I'm working on PostGIS 2.3, PostgreSQL 9.4

I have two tables : point and multilinestring, and in the context of a consistency control routine I created many queries. One of them is about checking that the points are not isolated (ie not connected to the lines). But for some reason, even if in QGIS I, in my sense, properly snap the lines on the point, it seems there is a problem with the geometry since I do not get the expected results of the query. Here is the query (for simplification purposes, I just try to get the id of the lines that touches the points).

```
SELECT DISTINCT point.id, line.id FROM point
    LEFT JOIN line ON st_touches(line.geom, point.geom);
```

I tried some other queries to try and understand what is happening, and if I change st_touches to st_intersects with a st_buffer on the point geometry, it works. I also tried to simply get the lines that touches each other (since they should do so at the location of the points), but here again I do not get the expected results.

I also tried to st_linemerge the lines (since it is needed for the st_startpoint et st_endpoint functions) but again without satisfying results.

My projection systems are identical.

Would anyone have an idea on what could be the problem ?

I could provide the datas I am using, but I don't know how since there is some geometry (and therefore sqlfiddle is not an option).

Comment: if you snap the points to the lines, then ST_Touch will not work (see http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html). Maybe you should try st_within?

Comment: In my case, I snapped the lines to the points so this shouldn't be an issue. I'm going to see what's on the link you provided, thanks.

Comment: And I do not see anything related to the snapping problem you mention. Would you have an explanation on how or why it is a problem? BTW ST_Within doesn't work neither, I guess the problem comes from the geometry...

Comment: Because when points snapped to line (or the other way round) ST_Touch fails as explained in the link above, because it checks if the point is touches an end of the line, but not if it is on the line

Comment: the line itself being the linestrings *interior*, whereas by definition the start/end points are the *boundary*...touching the *interior* is considered invalid for `ST_Touches`. whats wrong with plain old `ST_Intersects`?

Comment: @Mazu_R Ok, I am almost sure it worked before with the st_touches on other cases, while I am always snapping my lines to points... What would be the way to go then in QGIS to be sure of the topology?

Comment: @ThingumaBob I wasn't clear enough in my post I guess: I am looking to the start/end points, I do not want the points that may intersect the line. And the simple st_intersects does not work either.